# Error printing out the JSON file as required in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, output

I'm trying to read a JSON file in Android Studio. I'm having an error in printing out the accurate results on the emulator.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray games = jsonObj.getJSONArray("games");

            for (int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject g = games.getJSONObject(i);
                String schedule = g.getString("scheduled");
                String state = g.getString("status");

                JSONObject venue = g.getJSONObject("venue");
                String city = venue.getString("city");

                JSONObject home = g.getJSONObject("home");
                String name1 = home.getString("name");

                JSONObject away = g.getJSONObject("away");
                String name2 = away.getString("name");

                // tmp hash map for single fixture
                HashMap<String, String> fixture = new HashMap<>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                fixture.put("scheduled", schedule);
                fixture.put("status", state);
                fixture.put("city", city);
                fixture.put("name", name1);
                fixture.put("name", name2);

                // adding contact to contact list
                fixtureList.add(fixture);
            }
```

Here is my onPostExecute function:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, fixtureList,
                    R.layout.list_match_item, new String[]{"name", "scheduled", "status", "city",
                    "name"}, new int[]{R.id.fixture_away_team, R.id.fixture_date,
                    R.id.fixture_status,R.id.fixture_city, R.id.fixture_home_team});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Here is the JSON file:

[image]

Here is what it looks like on Emulator:

[image]

Name of the 'away team' is overlapping and is being printed out for 'home team' also. What could be wrong? How can I print both the name of the teams with the same object - "name" separately?

Comment: `fixture.put("name", name1);`, `fixture.put("name", name2);` - You're using the same key for both team names. Make those different; e.g., `"home_name"` and `"away_name"`. You'll need to change those in the `SimpleAdapter` constructor call, too.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the reply! I have already tried that and to my notice, the app crashes and doesn't load anything. I can not change - "names" to "home_name" as no such term is present in the JSON file, so it wouldn't detect it! I would be happy to know if there is any other way around!

Comment: The `Map` you're creating has no direct relation to the JSON you're parsing. It doesn't matter what keys you use to put values into the map, as long as you use the same ones to pull the values from the `Map`; i.e., as long as you use the same keys in the `SimpleAdapter` constructor call. The `Map` keys do not have to match the JSON keys. Make the changes I specified above, then change the array in the `SimpleAdapter` constructor call to `new String[]{"away_name", "scheduled", "status", "city", "home_name"}`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much mate! It solved my problem.